# why do I get NULL pointers with tinyXML2 in C++?

Tags: c++, tinyxml2

I'm new in the XML-parsing buisness. So sorry for silly questions.

I would like to navigate my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk103">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk104">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
      <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious 
      agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life 
      for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve 
      Ascendant.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk105">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>The Sundered Grail</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-09-10</publish_date>
      <description>The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters, 
      battle one another for control of England. Sequel to 
      Oberon's Legacy.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk106">
      <author>Randall, Cynthia</author>
      <title>Lover Birds</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-09-02</publish_date>
      <description>When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology 
      conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk107">
      <author>Thurman, Paula</author>
      <title>Splish Splash</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
      <description>A deep sea diver finds true love twenty 
      thousand leagues beneath the sea.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk108">
      <author>Knorr, Stefan</author>
      <title>Creepy Crawlies</title>
      <genre>Horror</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-06</publish_date>
      <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches,
      centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

whereas the code i am trying to run (following an internet tutorial) is:

```
tinyxml2::XMLDocument mappedxml1;
XMLError eResult = mappedxml1.LoadFile(filename1);
if(eResult == XML_SUCCESS){
        printf("XMLERROR is %d\nXML loading successfull.\n",eResult);
    }
    else{
        printf("XMLERROR is %d\nXML loading unsuccessfull.\n",eResult);
    }
XMLNode * pRoot1 = mappedxml1.FirstChild();
    if(pRoot1 == NULL){printf("ERROR: NO ROOT\n");}
    else{printf("Good pointer\n");}
XMLElement * pbook1 = pRoot1->FirstChildElement("book id");
    if (pbook1 == NULL){printf("ERROR PARSING ELEMENT\n");}
    else{printf("GOT IT\n");}
```

While `pRoot1` is good to go, the value of `pbook1` is always `NULL`.
I would expect it to point to `bk101`

any help or suggestions?
thank you in advance

Comment: Even when your program failed to load XML you are continuing the process.

Answer (score 6):

**You're trying to find an element named `book id`. There is no such element.**

There are, however, elements with the name `book`!
(And each one has an *attribute* named `id`.)

**You'll also need the parser to skip your XML declaration**, which is currently being caught by the `FirstChild` call (so `*pRoot1` isn't what you think it is!). You could try `FirstChildElement("catalog")` there instead.

As an aside, I suggest reviewing your error handling procedures; at the moment, if `pRoot1` is a null pointer then you write a message to the console, then happily continue on to attempt dereferencing that null pointer.

Comment: you are abviously right.
I agree on the error management thing: I just copied parts of the whole code.

Nonetheless, how do I get pbook1  to point to the first book?

Comment: @Wing: By writing `book` instead of `book id`.

Comment: I've tried:
XMLElement * pbook1 = pRoot1->FirstChildElement("book id"); 
XMLElement * pbook1 = pRoot1->FirstChildElement("book");
XMLElement * pbook1 = pRoot1->FirstChildElement();

I always get NULL

Comment: @Wing: You probably need to skip over the XML declaration too. Examine the root node to see what it actually is. Which documentation are you using?

Comment: https://shilohjames.wordpress.com/2014/04/27/tinyxml2-tutorial/#XML-ExtractFromXMLDocument

Comment: @Wing: Yeah so notice that their example has no XML declaration. If you examine `*pRoot1` you'll probably see that it's _not_ called `catalog`. Try using `FirstChildElement` (rather than `FirstChild`) for the root node too.

Comment: It works... GREAT! As I told you I am new to the XML parsing. Thank you very much for your help!